# livecd-tools - ext4 errors

Tags: fedora, ext4, livecd, kickstart

I'm using livecd tools to build an ISO image customized to my liking.  It appears to build fine, but after booting up, I get a bunch of ext4fs errors indicating referenced inodes were deleted.  My custom post section copies some configuration files as well as manually installs some software.

How can I get rid of these errors?

#### EDIT #1

During the build process, I get these errors (I'm wondering if this may be causing the ext4 errors later on, of it is of no concern):

```
/etc/selinux/targeted/contexts/files/file_contexts: line 190 has invalid context system_u:object_r:nsd_conf_t:s0
/etc/selinux/targeted/contexts/files/file_contexts: line 263 has invalid context system_u:object_r:ctdbd_var_t:s0
/etc/selinux/targeted/contexts/files/file_contexts: line 389 has invalid context system_u:object_r:kdump_crash_t:s0
/etc/selinux/targeted/contexts/files/file_contexts: line 467 has invalid context system_u:object_r:condor_etc_rw_t:s0
/etc/selinux/targeted/contexts/files/file_contexts: line 609 has invalid context system_u:object_r:nsd_zone_t:s0
/etc/selinux/targeted/contexts/files/file_contexts: line 1166 has invalid context system_u:object_r:pesign_var_run_t:s0
/etc/selinux/targeted/contexts/files/file_contexts: line 1355 has invalid context system_u:object_r:nsd_zone_t:s0
/etc/selinux/targeted/contexts/files/file_contexts: line 1356 has invalid context system_u:object_r:openvpn_var_lib_t:s0
/etc/selinux/targeted/contexts/files/file_contexts: line 1375 has invalid context system_u:object_r:neutron_var_lib_t:s0

Exiting after 10 errors.
```

NOTE: I get these errors whether SELinux is enabled or not.  I'm not sure what SELinux is blocking, if anything as I don't get any SELinux notifications that there were any problems.

Also, if I do `dmesg | tail`, I notice that SELinux is setup for the loopback devices for the ext4 sparse file:

```
SELinux: initialized (dev loop5, type ext4), uses xattr
SELinux: initialized (dev loop6, type vfat), uses genfs_contexts
SELinux: initialized (dev loop6, type hfsplus), uses genfs_contexts
SELinux: initialized (dev loop6, type hfsplus), uses genfs_contexts
```

Comment: Can you post the actual error messages?

Comment: I'll have to re-run the build tomorrow.  From the top of my head, the error message is deleted inode referenced.  I get this while booting up to my system.  Also, I'm unable to login to the system even though grepping /etc/shadow (after mounting the image) indicates the users are active and the password is set.  Because I cannot login, debugging the problem is made worse.

Comment: These are the actual errors, I have built images with these errors and they work fine, provided I use selinux=0 on my kernel command line ...  I'm guessing when I copy files into the chroot env, that screws up selinux.